# using regex with sed to delete the line just below the matching pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I've to delete the line containing date and page number in this text.

I tried by deleting the line that occurs just below the row containing data for *invoice, amount, locker*. But can not figure out the correct regular expression for this.

> **Axis**
>
> Invoice Amount Locker
>
> 489        849560.94  12
>
> Wednesday, August 2014 Page 1##  to delete
>
> **UB99**
>
> Invoice    Amount  Locker
>
> 512        1204873.89        99
>
> Monday, February 2014 Page 4##  to delete

I am trying:

sed -i '/regular expression/{n; d;}'

Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the line you want to delete contains the "page", try to delete the line by matching page, some like this:

```
sed -i '/page/Id' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to delete next line after pattern match using `awk`

```
cat file
Axis
Invoice Amount Locker
489 849560.94 12
Wednesday, August 2014 Page 1## to delete
UB99
Invoice Amount Locker
512 1204873.89 99
Monday, February 2014 Page 4## to delete
```

```
awk '/^Invoice/ {i=2} i--!=1' file
Axis
Invoice Amount Locker
Wednesday, August 2014 Page 1## to delete
UB99
Invoice Amount Locker
Monday, February 2014 Page 4## to delete
```

If you like to delete line two hops down: just increase the `i`

```
awk '/^Invoice/ {i=3} i--!=1' file
Axis
Invoice Amount Locker
489 849560.94 12
UB99
Invoice Amount Locker
512 1204873.89 99
```

---

Here is another way.  Its storing line number and delete what we do not want:

```
awk '/^Invoice/ {n=NR} !(n && NR==n+1)' file
Axis
Invoice Amount Locker
Wednesday, August 2014 Page 1## to delete
UB99
Invoice Amount Locker
Monday, February 2014 Page 4## to delete
```

```
awk '/^Invoice/ {n=NR} !(n && NR==n+2)' file
Axis
Invoice Amount Locker
489 849560.94 12
UB99
Invoice Amount Locker
512 1204873.89 99
```